# Gensim pretrained model similarity

Tags: python, vector, nlp, gensim, word2vec

Problem :

Im using glove pre-trained model with vectors to retrain my model with a specific domain say #cars, after training I want to find similar words within my domain but I got words not in my domain corpus, I believe it's from glove's vectors.

```
model_2.most_similar(positive=['spacious'],    topn=10)

[('bedrooms', 0.6275501251220703),
 ('roomy', 0.6149100065231323),
 ('luxurious', 0.6105825901031494),
 ('rooms', 0.5935696363449097),
 ('furnished', 0.5897485613822937),
 ('cramped', 0.5892841219902039),
 ('courtyard', 0.5721820592880249),
 ('bathrooms', 0.5618442893028259),
 ('opulent', 0.5592212677001953),
 ('expansive', 0.555268406867981)]
```

Here I expect something like leg-room, car's spacious features mentioned in the domain's corpus. How can we exclude the glove vectors while having similar vectors?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may not be enough info in a simple set of generic word-vectors to filter neighbors by domain-of-use.

You could try using a mixed-weighting: combine the similarities to `'spacious'`, and to `'cars'`, and return the top results in that combination – and it might help a little.

Supplying more than one `positive` word to the `most_similar()` method might approximate this. If you're sure of some major sources of interference/overlap, you might even be able to use `negative` word examples, similar to how word2vec finds candidate answers for analogies (though this might also suppress useful results that are legitimately related to both domains, like `'roomy'`). For example:

```
candidates = vec_model.most_similar(positive=['spacious', 'car'], 
                                    negative=['house'])
```

(Instead of using single words like 'car' or 'house' you could also try using vectors combined from many words that define a domain.)

But a sharp distinction sounds like a research project, rather than something easily possible with off-the-shelf libraries/vectors – and may requires more sophisticated approaches and datasets.

You could also try using a set of vectors trained only on a dataset of text from the domain of interest – thus ensuring the vocabulary, and senses, of words are all in that domain.

Comment: But I don't want the similar vectors too if it is not in my specified corpus. Want to know how impactful that particular feature is to that particular corpus(like Audi a8 car) !! so giving in negative will give good similar results but leads to false positives too, only want vectors within the corpus!! 

Thanks

Comment: When you load a set of vectors, all results will be from that set of vectors – unless you add some filtering of your own. If you train a new set of vectors on your corpus, only words in your corpus will exist in that new set, so it will be impossible to get back words not in your corpus. Otherwise, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Messed up there :-)

Our model holds pre-trained corpus vectors  + custom corpus vectors 

when finding similarity we don't want words from pre-trained corpus, how can we filter out them and have similar words from our custom corpus.

Comment: If you have a list of your "custom corpus words" in `our_words`, and `candidates` is the full list of similar results with their similarity scores (as returned by `most_similar()`, then that's a simple line of Python: `candidates_filtered = [result for result candidates if result[0] in our_words]`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot exclude the words from already trained model. I don't know in which framework you're working on but I'll give you the examples in Keras as it's simple to understand the intentions.

What you could do is use Embedding layer, populate it with GloVe "knowledge" and then resume training with your corpus so that layer will learn the words and fit them for your specific domain. You can read more about it in [Keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html)